# Error in running swift app on physical device with Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging

I'm trying to run my Xcode app on a physical device(I added firebase and pod files to my application). Here is an error - command PhaseSxcriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code. Anyone can help please, what's wrong? Running on simulators is okay.
The error appears in "Run custom shell script '[CP] Embed pods Frameworks'

Comment: "command PhaseSxcriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code"  That's not the exact error message you are getting, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps

1. Remove old pods folder.
2. Remove pods.lock file.
3. Remove project.workspace file.
4. Remove derived data.
5. ReInstall pods (make sure pods compatible & latest version)
6. Check Run scripts added properly if you are using any firebase or pods that require run script in the Build phase.
   7.clean build & run.

Also just open the iOS folder in Xcode and then try to run. Make sure your iPhone device UDID is added to the provisioning profile because sometimes it also causes issues.
You will get an exact error while you trying to run your app in Xcode editor.

Comment: I tried all this...

Comment: can you share a screenshot of the error?

Comment: Also, check once my answer last steps. i edited my answer just  check it once.